# Python: Error while running saved SVM model: ValueError: X has 2943 features, but SVC is expecting 330320 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deployment, svm

I have created an `SVM model` using `Sickit-learn`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\aaa\Documents\bbb\svm_.csv", encoding='latin1', sep=';')

from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
oversampler = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=42)

X_resampled, y_resampled = oversampler.fit_resample(df.drop(columns=['alvo']), df['alvo'])

df_resampled = pd.concat([X_resampled, pd.DataFrame({'alvo': y_resampled})], axis=1)

print(df_resampled)

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

X = df_resampled.drop(columns=['alvo'])
y = df_resampled['alvo']

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
X_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

svm_classifier = SVC(kernel='poly', random_state=42)

svm_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = svm_classifier.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
classification_report_result = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)

print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
print("Classification Report:\n", classification_report_result)

import pickle

model_file_path = "C:\\Users\\aaa\\Documents\\bbb\\svm_modelo_sent_simnao2.pkl"

with open(model_file_path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(svm_classifier, f)

print("Model saved successfully!")
```

That simple implemention of Support Vector Machines to predict an categorical variable was correct, worked fine.

But, when loading the model and running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import joblib

model_file_path = "C:\\Users\\AAA\\Documents\\BBB\\svm_modelo_sent_simnao.pkl"
svm_classifier = joblib.load(model_file_path)

new_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\AAA\Documents\BBB\svm_simnao_rodar.csv", encoding='latin1', sep=';')

X_new = new_df.drop(columns=['alvo', 'ID_ASSUNTO'], axis=1)  # Drop 'alvo' and 'ID_ASSUNTO' columns

categorical_columns = ['UF', 'TIPO_ACAO', 'AREA_JURIDICA', 'VARA_CAMARA', 'CLIENTE_NOME']  # List of categorical columns
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False)
X_new_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(X_new[categorical_columns])

X_new_processed = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_new_encoded), X_new.drop(columns=categorical_columns)], axis=1)

y_pred_new = svm_classifier.predict(X_new_processed)

new_df['alvo'] = y_pred_new

predictions = new_df[['ID_ASSUNTO', 'alvo']]

print(predictions)
```

What results in the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-522717c33138> in <module>
     22 
     23 # Make predictions
---> 24 y_pred_new = svm_classifier.predict(X_new_processed)
     25 
     26 # Add predictions ('alvo') to the new data

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in predict(self, X)
    818             y = np.argmax(self.decision_function(X), axis=1)
    819         else:
--> 820             y = super().predict(X)
    821         return self.classes_.take(np.asarray(y, dtype=np.intp))
    822 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in predict(self, X)
    431             The predicted values.
    432         """
--> 433         X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
    434         predict = self._sparse_predict if self._sparse else self._dense_predict
    435         return predict(X)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in _validate_for_predict(self, X)
    611 
...
--> 389             raise ValueError(
    390                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    391                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."

ValueError: X has 2943 features, but SVC is expecting 330320 features as input.
```

---

The data i'm using to predict alvo in the deployment code have the exact same structure as the data which i trained the model and I use `OneHotEncoding` in both training and deployment code... so I'm kinda lost in this one.

Any idea of how can i resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The model file path (model_file_path) that you saved looks different from the one you load. Can you check this? Then, can you give the shape of X_train that you used in the first part as input to svm.fit  (X_train.shape) and the shape of X_new_processed that you used as input to predict in the second part?